# Use supremum and infimum principle prove the Heine-Borel theorem

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

Assume there is a closed and bounded interval A $\in \mathbb R$, A=$[a,b]$. Also, there is a collection of infinite open intervals:$\{U_i |i\in I\}$ that forms an open cover of A.

Claim: A can be covered by only finitely many open intervals in its $\{U_i |i\in I\}$

Prove by contradiction.

---

Suppose A can only be covered by infinitely many open intervals. Then take a collection of finite open intervals in $\{U_i |i\in I\}$ $(m,n)$ and let it cover part of A(a subset of A). This part is denoted as $p=\{x|x\in[a,c] \}$. Because set $p$ is bounded above by $b$, then it has a supremum, and because of $c\in A$, max(p)=$c$

---

edit：
Suppose A can only be covered by infinitely many open intervals. This means that any finite collection of open intervals in $\{U_i |i\in I\}$ can only over part of the interval A.Then it's possible to take a collection of finite open intervals $\{U_1, U_2,..., U_n\}$ $\subset$ $\{U_i |i\in I\}$ such that the union of these finite open intervals cover $[a,c]$ which is a subset of A.

If $c \neq b$, then it can be :$ x\leq c<b,\forall x\in A$. Because $\{U_i |i\in I\}$ covers A, there exists a open interval $(p,q)$ with $(p,q) \subset [a,b]$ that covers $c$

Thus, $c<q<b$, and there exists $y=\frac{c+q}{2}$ such that  $c<y<q<b$. Then, take the union of (m,n)and(p,q), these are two (finite) open intervals and they cover the interval A, and $y$. Thus, $y\in A$, and this is the contradiction with the fact that $c$ is the supremum of interval A.
Hence, $c$ can't be less than $b$
I’m not sure whether my proof is correct.

Comment: "Then take a collection of finite open intervals in $\{U_i \mid i \in I\}$ $(m, n)$" - what exactly does this mean? What are $m$ and $n$? Isn't $\{U_i \mid i \in I\}$ fixed?

Comment: My idea is that $\{U_i |i\in I\}$ has infinite open intervals that cover the entire [a,b]. Then I only pick finitely many of them, and these finite intervals should cover only part of [a,b]. Then because $\{U_i |i\in I\}$ covers [a,b], it's possible to  take some open intervals covering [a,c] which is the subset of[a,b]. Then take the union of these finite open intervals to be only one open interval (m,n) which covers [a,c].

Comment: Your attempt still doesn't make sense. Please be explicit about exactly what you are picking/taking. For example, if you're taking some collection of intervals from the given set, you should say "Take some $U_{i_1}, \ldots, U_{i_n}$ such that $\ldots$".

Comment: I edit some, and I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: “and this is in contradiction with the fact that $c$ is the supremum of interval $A$” Nowhere is it assumed or proved that $c$ is the supremum of $A$.

Comment: I think that is because of the supremum and infimum principle, since A is obviously bounded above and it is on $\mathbb R$, then A should have its supremum which I denote as c

Comment: Then how do you know that it’s possible to cover $[a, c]$ with a finite number of intervals? This is just circular reasoning.

Comment: The reason I give [a,c] is that because I suppose [a,b] can only be covered by infinitely many subcovers. Then I choose finitely many, and it definitely can't cover the entire [a,b] but it's possible to pick finitely many that cover [a,c] for example$\{U_1, U_2,..., U_n\}$ I can just claim that $U_1 $ covers a, ...., $U_n$ covers c